# TableViewCell will be not displayed completely

Tags: swift, uitableview, constraints

I want to display the following default cell if no posts are available:

[image]

This time, my cell will be displayed like that:

[image]

I already set the following codelines in `viewDidLoad`:

```
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 150
tableView.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
```

In my `cellForRowAt` I have set the following lines:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    switch self.postArray.count {

    case 0:
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "KeineBeiträgeVorhanden")!
        return cell

    default:

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "DiscoveryCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! DiscoveryCollectionViewCell
```

But my TableViewCell is not displayed in the right size.
Thanks in advance for your help!

Merry Christmas to all!!!

Comment: Can you share your vertical constraints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Image constraints

```
( top , centerX ) => to superView , width , height
```

label constraints

```
top => to image , ( leading , trailing , bottom ) => to superView
```

and `.lines = 0`

Comment: Thanks. The problem was a missing constraint from the label to the bottom of the tableviewcell.